# How do I find what sensors are available in a phone using Andorid?

Tags: android, sensors

I want to develop an App that can find the available sensors in a phone and configure the app accordingly. How do I find the type and number of sensors available in a phone programmatically? Not all phone hardware are same and they vary with different types of sensors, for example, some may have a gps and some may not. Is there any library that I can use to find types of sensors  available in a specific phone running Android?

Answer (score 1):

> How do I find the type and number of sensors available in a phone programmatically?

First, you need to decide what you think a "sensor" is.

> for example, some may have a gps and some may not

In Android, GPS is not a "sensor", any more than a button is. You are welcome to consider such things to be "sensors", but unless you are willing to **completely and precisely** list what you think "sensors" are, you will not be able to get complete and precise answers.

To find out what Android sensors are in a given device, call `getSensorList()` on `SensorManager`. To find out what Android location providers are in a given device (e.g., GPS), call `getProviders()` on `LocationManager` with a suitable `Criteria` describing the capabilities you need.